# Where is the "Scripts Window" menu in Blender 2.59?

Tags: blender

I'm trying to import a script into Blender, and I have the script in my directory and I pushed F8 to reload scripts, but the instructions for running this script say:

> In the "Scripts Window" run "Scripts → Export → OGRE Meshes".

I've seen other similar instructions for other scripts. But the toolbar only contains "File/Add/Render/Help." Changing the "screen layout" to Scripting doesn't reveal any additional options, either.

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those instructions are for Blender 2.49 and before. Scripting API is completely different (and much better) since 2.5.
Import and export is in the file menu. What you are looking for is the add-on list, where you can enable them and see where are they located. File -> User preferences... -> Add-ons.

Maybe you need to install the appropiate add-on for blender 2.5x, if it exists.

Edit: it's still in development but here it is: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Blender+2.5+Exporter

Comment: Hmm.. I couldn't find the script in the list of addons anywhere, even after I located it with "Install Add-On." I'm guessing because the scripts were written pre-2.5, they aren't compatible. I didn't know about the work-in-progress, though. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is now called "Python console", do you see this option somewhere?

**Edit**: In [**this post**](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=64868#p428941) they confirm that, from Blender 2.5x, Script Window is now called Python console

Comment: Yes, but they don't mention how to run scripts from the console. I'm sure there's a way, but I'm going to stick with the UI version.